# How to implement cleanup function in useEffect while fetching data from API in contex provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display a list of products based on specific categories fetched from api, like below:

```js
const API = "https://dummyjson.com/products";

const ProductsList = () => {
  const { cate } = useParams(); //here I am getting category from Viewall component
  const { getFilterProducts, filter_products } = useFilterContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    getFilterProducts(`${API}/category/${cate}`);
  }, [cate]);
  return (
    <div className="mx-2 mt-2 mb-16 md:mb-0 grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-12">
      <div className="h-9 w-full md:col-span-2">
        <FilterSection />
      </div>
      <div className="md:col-span-10">
        <ProductListDetails products={filter_products} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My FilterContextProvider is as follows

```js
const initialState = {
  filter_products: [],
};

const FilterProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const { products } = useAppContext();
  const getFilterProducts = async (url) => {
    dispatch({ type: "FILTERS_LOADING" });
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();
      if (!res.ok) {
        var error = new Error("Error" + res.status + res.statusText);
        throw error;
      }
      dispatch({ type: "LOAD_FILTER_PRODUCTS", payload: data.products });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "FILTERS_ERROR", payload: err.message });
    }
  };
  return (
    <FilterContext.Provider value={{ ...state, getFilterProducts }}>
      {children}
    </FilterContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I tried using this simple approach in my `ProductList` component to clean up:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let inView = true;
  getFilterProducts(`${API}/category/${cate}`);

  return () => {
    inView = false;
  };
}, [cate]);
```

But it does not seem to work. When I move to the `ProductList` component, it first displays data of my previous `filer_products` value, then after a few fractions of seconds, updates the data and shows current data.
I am expecting that when the `ProductList` component unmounts, its rendered data should vanish, and when I navigate it again, it should render the current data directly, not after a fraction seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you explained, I assume your context is wrapping your routes, and it's not re-rendering when switching between pages. A simple solution is to have a loader in `ProductsList`, wait for the new data to replace the old, and have the user notice what's happening with a loader:

```js
const ProductsList = () => {
  const { cate } = useParams(); //here I am getting category from Viewall component
  const { getFilterProducts, filter_products } = useFilterContext();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    getFilterProducts(`${API}/category/${cate}`).then(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, [cate]);

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Hang tight, the data is being fetched...</p>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="mx-2 mt-2 mb-16 md:mb-0 grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-12">
      <div className="h-9 w-full md:col-span-2">
        <FilterSection />
      </div>
      <div className="md:col-span-10">
        <ProductListDetails products={filter_products} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you need to clear your store in a clean-up function, you can add `dispatch` as part of your context value, grab it in `ProductsList` and call it like so:

```
<FilterContext.Provider value={{ ...state, getFilterProducts, dispatch }}>
  {children}
</FilterContext.Provider>
```

```js
const { getFilterProducts, filter_products, dispatch } = useFilterContext();
useEffect(() => {
  getFilterProducts(`${API}/category/${cate}`);

  return () => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD_FILTER_PRODUCTS", payload: {} });
  };
}, [cate]);
```

Comment: Thanks man. It solved my problem. Such a silly question but sometimes it does not click in mind. But again thanks for your help. I did not know about second option, that we can implement it like this also. Today you helped me to know another method to implement which I wasn't aware. Once again thanks because I learned new things because of you.

Comment: My pleasure @PrinceSingh! And it's totally normal. Sometimes, we all need another person who will be able to provide a fresh outlook on an issue, which may be simple, but we might not see it.